# Hasura Graphql endpoing throwing 504 Error

Tags: graphql, hasura, http-status-code-504

When I tried to execute a query in hasura console, the response returns 504 after 20.20s.
How to solve this? Is hasura application to have any environment variables to configure the request timeout?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to miss of foreign key index. After the troubleshooting and found that, when configuring foreign key relationships, it is good practice to add an index of the same. It will change the query execution plan.